# Error 438 from using Filesystemobject.OpentTextFile but not on my computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Note: I'm new to using Visual Studio and writing code outside of VB6 and VBA.  Also, I've resolved my problem by using IO.File.

However, I really want to learn why this wouldn't work:

```
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim FSOts As TextStream
FSOts = FSO.OpenTextFile(filepath1, IOMode.ForReading, True)
While FSOts.AtEndOfStream = False
    temp = FSOts.ReadLine()
    MsgBox(temp)
    tempcollection.Add(temp)
 End While
 FSOts.Close()
```

It works on my computer, but for some reason it won't on others.  I've used this object in a vb script before but in that situation the 2nd argument was 'ForReading' and was written in a different IDE (FEMAP) which referenced the 32bit scrrun.dll.  In Visual Studio I noticed the scripting library is pointing to syswow64; I'm not sure if that makes any difference.  All distributed sites run 64 bit OS and have this library.  In any case I get an error 438 when I try to use:

```
FSOts = FSO.OpenTextFile(filepath1, IOMode.ForReading, True)
```

VS will not let me compile it with just 'ForReading'.

Again, I've used this object before in vb6 but the 2nd argument was not iomode.forreading but 'ForReading'.  In that situation it worked fine on the same machines that are giving me problems (except for mine of course!).

Comment: In VB6, you could type in enum such as `ForReading` whereas in VS.NET you will use `IOMode.ForReading`. What is the description of error 438? I am on a 64 bit OS and scripting runtime refers to c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll

Comment: Just use IO.File. Forget about old technology when you have a choice.

Comment: shahkalpesh: When I look at my references under project properties it indicates that i'm referencing the syswow64 one.  Anyways error 438 is described as 'Object doesn't support this property or method'  so it seems to be some compatibility/revision issue between machines.